# show elements of array with determined value first

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
$array = [
    ['brand' => 'bmw', 'type' => 'car'],
    ['brand' => 'yahaha', 'type' => 'bike'],
    ['brand' => 'specialized', 'type' => 'bycicle'],
    ['brand' => 'toyota', 'type' => 'car'],
    ['brand' => 'honda', 'type' => 'bike']
]
```

How can i show the 'cars' first and then all the others? i'm going nuts.
something like this -> `bmw, toyota, yahaha, specialized, honda`.

tks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uasort` is your choice:

```php
<?php
$array = [
    ['brand' => 'bmw', 'type' => 'car'],
    ['brand' => 'yahaha', 'type' => 'bike'],
    ['brand' => 'specialized', 'type' => 'bycicle'],
    ['brand' => 'toyota', 'type' => 'car'],
    ['brand' => 'honda', 'type' => 'bike']
];

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a['type'] == 'car' ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
```

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => bmw
            [type] => car
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [brand] => toyota
            [type] => car
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [brand] => honda
            [type] => bike
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [brand] => specialized
            [type] => bycicle
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand] => yahaha
            [type] => bike
        )

)
```

To extract the `brand` column:

```php
print_r(array_column($array, 'brand'));
```

```php
Array
(
    [0] => toyota
    [1] => bmw
    [2] => yahaha
    [3] => specialized
    [4] => honda
)
```

Comment: tku. i think this is perfect =) i was looking for sorting but didnt know that you could do a function like that. tks again =)

Comment: Yes, you could even do more detailed comparisons in that `cmp` function if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to just make two passes through the array when you output, skipping non-cars the first time and cars the second time.

```
foreach ($array as $vehicle) {
    if ($vehicle['type'] == 'car') {
        echo $vehicle['brand'];
    }
}

foreach ($array as $vehicle) {
    if ($vehicle['type'] != 'car') {
        echo $vehicle['brand'];
    }
}
```